# How fuser identified the issue - Cannot stat file /proc/1234/fd/3: Stale file handle?

Tags: linux, inode, fuser

Can someone explain how fuser -u  reported this error and even how to recreate this in Linux? fuser didn't tell me exact file name, but just process information for file set and now the issue disappeared. How to get more info about this issue (maybe by using specific fuser options or other tools)? How to fix it so fuser will not print the error? Is there a chance that actual file was in use?